# ienumerable <string> to dictionary <string, int>

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I'm using the following code to split array of strings into list.

```
private List<string> GenerateTerms(string[] docs)
    {
        return docs.SelectMany(doc => ProcessDocument(doc)).Distinct().ToList();
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> ProcessDocument(string doc)
    {
        return doc.Split(' ')
                  .GroupBy(word => word)
                  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                  .Select(g => g.Key)
                  .Take(1000);
    }
```

What I want to do is replace the list returned with

```
Dictionary <string, int>
```

i.e. instead of returned list , i want to return Dictionary

Could anyone help ?? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string doc = "This is a test sentence with some words with some words repeating like: is a test";
var result = doc.Split(' ')
                   .GroupBy(word => word)
                   .OrderByDescending(g=> g.Count())
                   .Take(1000)
                   .ToDictionary(r => r.Key ,r=> r.Count());
```

**EDIT:**

I believe you are looking to get a final dictionary from array of strings, based on words as key and their final count as values. Since dictionary can't contain duplicate values, so you will not be required to use `Distict`. 
You have to re-write your methods as:

```
private Dictionary<string,int> GenerateTerms(string[] docs)
{
    List<Dictionary<string, int>> combinedDictionaryList = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();
    foreach (string str in docs)
    {
        //Add returned dictionaries to a list
        combinedDictionaryList.Add(ProcessDocument(str));
    }
    //return a single dictionary from list od dictionaries
    return combinedDictionaryList
            .SelectMany(dict=> dict)
            .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
            .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Sum(value => value));
}

private Dictionary<string,int> ProcessDocument(string doc)
{
    return doc.Split(' ')
            .GroupBy(word => word)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .Take(1000)
            .ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.Count());
}
```

Then you can call it like:

```
string[] docs = new[] 
    {
        "This is a test sentence with some words with some words repeating like: is a test",
        "This is a test sentence with some words with some words repeating like: is a test",
        "This is a test sentence with some words",
        "This is a test sentence with some words",
    };

Dictionary<string, int> finalDictionary = GenerateTerms(docs);
```

Comment: But i have many docs. does this this code do what i need in the original post??

Comment: @Qaesar, do you want your method `GenerateTerms` to return a combined dictionary of all the elements in the string array ?

Comment: @ Habib, ... 1- split, group, sort and take (1000) for each doc of docs and then combine all docs into one dictionary with no duplicate elements (Distinct)

Comment: @Qaesar, so for merged dictionaries you want to add the count for each word together against a single key ?

Comment: @Qaesar, check the edited answer, if this is what you are looking for

Comment: #Habib .... Why you are using 'Tolookup ?? the final dictionary i want  doesn't mater if it is sorted or not ... can I ignore it ?

Comment: @Qaesar Wow, it is very bulky! Look at my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string[] docs = {"aaa bbb", "aaa ccc", "sss, ccc"};        

var result = docs.SelectMany(doc => doc.Split())
                 .GroupBy(word => word)
                 .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                 .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count())
                 .Take(1000);
```

**EDIT:**

```
var result = docs.SelectMany(
        doc => doc.Split()
            .GroupBy(word => word)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
            .Take(1000))
    .Select(g => new {Word = g.Key, Cnt = g.Count()})
    .GroupBy(t => t.Word)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(t => t.Cnt));
```

Comment: @Qaesar , "take (1000) for each doc" - sorry my mistake !

Comment: @Qaesar Wow, i have negative feedback! Answer updated. What you thing about this?

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional cruft the following should work.

```
return doc.Split(' ')
          .GroupBy(word => word)
          .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Tailor it via `Take`, `OrderBy` etc as is necessary for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    var keys = new List<string>();
    var values = new List<string>();
    var dictionary = keys.ToDictionary(x => x, x => values[keys.IndexOf(x)]);
```